# How to create or where I can find a symbol of a fly?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw the following figure, a chessboard with a fly in the house on the left top. But I can't to dry a fly.
[image]

Comment: You have the `\PHbee` icon in `phaistos`-package that might match what you're looking for (cf. [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol Lis](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) on p. 138)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use a fly drawn with tikz you can use this code, that is a transcription from [this SVG](http://www.clker.com/cliparts/K/4/S/M/S/O/green-fly-green-for-web.svg).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.21, yscale=-1, ultra thick]
    \draw svg{M423.7 480c24.3 8.3 51.3 11 71.3 28 17 12 30 30 50.3 36.2 8.8 4 17.6 8.5 24.6 15.2};
    \draw svg{M420 471.4c27.3 -20 22.7 -56 28.4 -85 8.6 -22.7 21 -49.8 43.5 -61.2};
    \draw svg{M346 465c -6.8 -27.7 -33.5 -44.6 -42.3 -71.4 -3 -7 -2 -14.8 -4.6 -21.7 -4 -11 -11 -20 -17 -29 -5 -5 -11 -8 -15 -14m79 149c -24 8 -51 10.3 -71 28 -17 12 -29.5 30 -50 36 -8.6 4 -17.3 8.2 -24.3 15};
    \draw svg{M354 496c -7.6 12.7 -24 12 -36.2 16.6 -7.8 2.7 -13 9.3 -19.7 13.6 -14 11 -27 25.7 -31 44 -7 17.2 -17 33 -29 46.7 -4 3 -8.6 6 -11.6 11};
    \draw svg{M413.7 500.2c26.2 7 45.6 27.3 64.8 45.2 16.2 17.4 20 43 38 59 12 12 26.7 21.8 35.2 36.8};
    \fill svg{M432.2 553.7c0 41 -21 108 -49.4 108s -45.3 -68 -45.3 -109 19 -49.4 47.4 -49.4c28 0 47 9.5 47 50.4z};
    \fill svg{M428 476.5c0 15.4 -17.7 38 -42 38 -24.5 0 -46.4 -22.6 -46.4 -38 0 -15.3 19.7 -58.3 44.2 -58.3 24.4 0 44.3 43 44.3 58.3z};
    \fill svg{M407.7 392 c 8.8 17.6 24 35.2 12 40.4 -18 7.8 -45.6 6.3 -59.3 .8 -26.7 -5.4 -5 -23 4 -40 8.4 -16.2 12 -30 22.2 -18 10.5 -8.7 12.5 -0.4 21 17z};
    \fill[gray, opacity=.7] svg{M484 577.4c22.6 44.6 25.4 124.8 -1.5 138.4 -26.8 13.7 -73.2 -44.4 -95.8 -89 -11.4 -22.3 -27.5 -53.5 -26 -72.5 1.3 -19 20.2 -26 33.6 -33 13.4 -6.8 18.8 -57.4 35 -47.3 16.3 10 43.3 81 54.7 103.4z};
    \fill[gray, opacity=.7] svg{M280.5 579.5C258 624 255 704.3 282 718c26.8 13.5 73.2 -44.5 95.8 -89 11.4 -22.4 27.5 -53.6 26 -72.7 -1.2 -19 -20 -26 -33.6 -33 -13.4 -6.7 -18.8 -57.4 -35 -47.2 -16.2 11 -43.2 82 -54.7 104z};
    \fill svg{M421.4 397.3a14.4 15.4 0 1 0 -29 0 14.4 15.4 1 1 1 29 0z};
    \fill svg{M378.2 395.2a14.4 15.4 0 1 0 -29 0 14.4 15.4 1 1 1 29 0z};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Kpym, Show! How to put color in Figure?

Answer (score 14):

I grab a fly image from the internet (http://derangedlacrimes.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/200px-Musca_illustration.png) and inset it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chessboard,stackengine,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\stackinset{l}{20pt}{t}{20pt}{%
  \rotatebox[origin=center]{-135}{\includegraphics[width=12pt]{200px-Musca_illustration}}}
{\setchessboard{boardfontsize=20pt}
\chessboard}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the border info is not wanted, apply a little `trimclip`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chessboard,stackengine,graphicx,trimclip}
\begin{document}
\stackinset{l}{2pt}{t}{2pt}{%
  \rotatebox[origin=center]{-135}{%
  \includegraphics[width=12pt]{200px-Musca_illustration}}}
  {\clipbox{18pt 18pt 18pt 18pt}{\setchessboard{boardfontsize=20pt}\chessboard}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your link doesnt allow hotlinking, here is a mirror http://stack.imgur.com/Lm0fE.png

Comment: Following ideas discussed here and even followed longer path, I made, changing the fly by an Ant.

Comment: @benedito To each man, his own bug.  Best wishes...